# Restore deleted docker container that is still running

Tags: docker

I accidentally deleted a docker container. (Via rm -R ) However, it's still running and sending data. Is it possible to restore it?

Comment: What about creating the Docker Container again? The image is still there and the volumes should be untouched.

Comment: How would that work?

Comment: There is no option -R for the docker rm command , you must have got an error and no wonder the container is still running.

Comment: I removed the directory containing the Dockerfile etc. via rm -R

Comment: What about https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-backup-and-restore-docker-containers/   ? 2 Seconds of using Google

Comment: The docker image and the running container image are in a different location and have no link to the dockerfile... What is that you would want to do ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm curios where you executed `rm -R`, i assume it was in your dev folders? i find it hard to imagine you actually accidently deleted the folders containing the volume/journal for the container itself.

If you run `docker container ps` what do you see? if your container is there and still running then run `docker container inspect containerNameOrSha` this will give you the directories which contain the data and the image which the container was created from.

If the containers directory really is gone?? how? i.e the actual file system then I cant see how the container is running! But lets find out. run `docker container exec -it containerNameOrSha sh` this will give you an interactive shell into the container. What can you see, are your files still here? are the processes you expect to see running?

If you want to get to the data inside the running container you can use `docker cp` which can copy data from your container to your host.

Its unclear 'why' you need to get this container back, maybe if you update your question someone might be able to get a better answer than this rather generic one.

Comment: I was able to restore the scripts that were lost by entering the container with your method, then copy pasting the script contents recovered by cat ... Thanks!